# Вопрос по checkboxlist

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть следующий список, если я нажимаю удалить график то он удаляется из checkboxlist. Как мне сделать, так чтобы обновлялись при этом данные в списке, потому что при нажатии на кнопку показать все выводит все графики, даже которые удалил.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int k1 = 0;
    GraphPane pane = zedGraph.GraphPane;
    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {

        checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true); // вкл все флаги
        if (Program.axisList[i].sumPoints == 0)
        {
            k1++;
            pane.CurveList[i + k1].IsVisible = true;
            pane.YAxisList[i + k1].IsVisible = true;
            pane.XAxis.IsVisible = true;
            labelOfAxis[i + k1].Visible = true;// показ всех подписей
        }
        else
        {
            pane.CurveList[i + k1].IsVisible = true;
            pane.YAxisList[i + k1].IsVisible = true;
            pane.XAxis.IsVisible = true;
            labelOfAxis[i + k1].Visible = true;// показ всех подписей
        }
    }
    k1 = 0;
    zedGraph.AxisChange();
    zedGraph.Invalidate();

}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int k2 = 0;
    GraphPane pane = zedGraph.GraphPane;
    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, false);// очищение списка

        if (Program.axisList[i].sumPoints == 0)
        {
            k2++;
            pane.CurveList[i + k2].IsVisible = false;
            pane.YAxisList[i + k2].IsVisible = false;
            pane.XAxis.IsVisible = false;
            labelOfAxis[i+k2].Visible = false;// показ всех подписей
        }
        else
        {
            pane.CurveList[i + k2].IsVisible = false;
            pane.YAxisList[i + k2].IsVisible = false;
            pane.XAxis.IsVisible = false;
            labelOfAxis[i+k2].Visible = false;// показ всех подписей
        }
    }
    k2 = 0;
    zedGraph.AxisChange();
    zedGraph.Invalidate();

}


private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int selested = checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex;
        bool relay = false;
        int nolIndex = 0;
        int k3 = 0;
        GraphPane pane = zedGraph.GraphPane;
        for (int i = 0; i < Program.axisList[0].sumAxis; i++)
        {
            if (Program.axisList[i].sumPoints == 0)
                nolIndex = i;

        }

        if (nolIndex != 0)
            relay = true;
        if (relay == true)
        {
            if (selested >= nolIndex)
            {
                k3 = 1;
                checkedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(selested);
                pane.CurveList[selested + k3].IsVisible = false;
                pane.YAxisList[selested + k3].IsVisible = false;
                labelOfAxis[selested + k3].Visible = false;
                pane.XAxis.IsVisible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                k3 = 0;
                checkedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(selested);
                pane.CurveList[selested + k3].IsVisible = false;
                pane.YAxisList[selested + k3].IsVisible = false;
                labelOfAxis[selested + k3].Visible = false;
                pane.XAxis.IsVisible = false;
            }
        }
        k3 = 0;
        zedGraph.AxisChange();
        zedGraph.Invalidate();
    }
    catch (ArgumentException exc)
    {
        // перехватить все исключения
        Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
        // Обработать ошибку. 
    }


}
```

`button1` - показать ,

`button2` -очистить,

`button3` - удалить график

Comment: удаляйте не только из списка но и из датасорса на основании которого формируете графики

Comment: Эм... А  это как?

Comment: затрудняюсь дать вам ответ, ибо вопрос у вас не полный, переформулируйте уго, добавте исходный код и тд. сейчас же это выглядит как "у меня машина красная, сколько будет стоить ремонт?"

Comment: button1 - показать ,button2-очистить, button3- удалить график

Comment: Хорошо, жду ответа.

Comment: У вас там есть в `Program.axisList`, который используется для постороения графиков. Когда удаляете элемент из списка, надо удалять и из него.

Comment: Нет, мне так не получится сделать, так как эти данные используются другими методами.  Мне их как то надо удалить только из списка.